# How to populate datatable with all possible instances of certain data?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I am having some trouble writing a SQL Server stored procedure. I have three tables, `Products`,`CustomerInfo` and `CustomerOrders`.

- `Products` has columns `ProductID,Product, Price, Description`
- `CustomerInfo` has columns `CostumerID, Name, Address, Zipcode`
- `CustomerOrders` has columns like `CustomerID or TransactionID, ProductID, Quantity`.

Now I am trying to write a stored procedure which will import into a datatable all the products the customer has ever bought. I have the customers name that I can use as an parameter.

Couple of things to note: every time a customer purchases something, a new `CustomerID` and `TransactionID` are generated and they are both the same. The `CustomerName` is the only constant across multiple orders.

```
DECLARE @TransactionID int;

SET @TransactionID = @Id;

SELECT 
    P.Product, P.Price, 
    CP.TotalProducts as ProductQuantity 
FROM 
    Products P
INNER JOIN 
    CustomerProducts CP ON CP.ProductID = P.ProductID
WHERE
    CP.CustomerID = @TransactionID
```

At the moment, I get the products that the customer bought the last time he shopped. However, I want to get all products he has ever bought into one table. If anyone can help me out, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: You create a new CustomerID and TransactionID with each purchase? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you need joins on 3 tables in stored procedure to extract all details of customer purchased products.

so a stored procedure in this purpose could look like this-

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[GetCustomerProductsById]  
( 
@CustId int=0
AS
BEGIN
SELECT P.ProductId ,P.Product,P.Price,P.Description,C.CustomerID,C.Name,C.Address FROM Products P
Inner Join CustomerOrders CO ON P.ProductId= CO.ProductID
Inner Join CustomerInfo C ON C.CustomerID = CO.CustomerID
WHERE C.CustomerID = @CustId
ORDER BY C.Name
END
```

Now once this is giving us the expected results then in c# code you can call this stored procedure like below and extract a result datatable.

```
SqlDataAdapter SqlAda;
DataSet ds; 
using (SqlConnection Sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strCon))    
{    
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())    
{

Sqlcon.Open();

cmd.Connection = Sqlcon;

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.CommandText = "GetCustomerProductsById";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustId", SqlDbType.Int, 50));

cmd.Parameters["@CustId"].Value = <Your Input Source>;  
SqlAda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

ds = new DataSet();

SqlAda.Fill(ds);

Datatable dt = new DataTable();
dt = ds.Tables[0];
}

}
```